# Delphi: Frame and State of ActionList - Error?

Tags: delphi, tframe, tform, tactionlist

I have an Action List on a Form and a Frame (a unit of a Form is impelemented in the Frame).

I set Form2.General.State:=**asSuspended** in the Frame, and I have an error: Undeclared identifier: 'asSuspended'.

The code works normally in the Form, but not in the Frame.

Why?

Thanks!!!

Comment: What does "a unit of a Form is impelemented in the Frame" mean?

Comment: I suppose that `General` is a `TActionList` that is a part of your `TForm2`?

Comment: If I were you, I'd start learning basic Delphi (and OOP) programming terminology, such as `unit`, `class`, and `object` (=instance of class).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you just have to add `ActnList` to the `uses` clause of the unit in which the error appears.

Comment: I told you to add `ActnList`, not `General`.

Comment: The problem was that the compiler didn't know what `asSuspended` was. Therefore, you need to add `ActnList`, the unit in which `asSuspended` is defined. `General` is the *name* that *you* gave to a particular instance of a `TActionList` -- of course there is no *unit* called `General`!

Comment: You should not add `General` to the uses list! There is no unit called `General`! You should add `ActnList` to the uses list, because `ActnList` is the unit in which `asSuspended` is defined! That is, do NOT write `uses General`. Instead, write `uses ActnList`.

Answer (score 3):

Add the unit in which `asSuspended` is defined to the uses clause of the frame unit.

Comment: sorry, Andreas Rejbrand was first. You have the same answers :)

Comment: @Andreas I even typed it on my E52!

Comment: @maxfax I think you should give it to @Andreas since he helped you the most in the comments.